# Can't read object property

Tags: javascript

I've this object structure (Chrome console output):

```
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
```

This 3 object are contained in one object called `response`, the response object contains all data to insert in my scheduler (but this isn't important).

Now each object have this property:

```
appointments: Array[2]
unavailables: Array[1]
```

I'm interested to get the unavailables property. Not all the three object is valorized, infact the object `1` as index, contains only the `appointments` data, the `unavailables` array is empty.

Now for the first object all working fine, `the object 0`, for the second object `object 1 as index`, I perform a condition for avoid the undefined property. The last one object is the problem, infact the data returned isn't correct.
If I print the object 2 as follow (outside the for):

```
response[2]['unavailables'][0].id_users_provider
```

I get this: `92` and the result is correct.
 But the foreach return a wrong value, this s my code:

```
for(var z = 0; z < response.length; z++)
{
    if(response[z]['unavailables'][z] != undefined)
    {
         var id_operatore = response[z]['unavailables'][0].id_users_provider;
         console.log(id_operatore);
    }
}
```

Chrome console return:

> 89
>   89 <- this should be 92!

Other information for the iterested object:

```
2: Object
         appointmens: Array[1]
         unavailables: Array[1]
                      0: Object
                                id: 189
                                id_users_provider:92
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do all of the objects look like? Could you do console.log(response) and post that?

Comment: I've already inserted the response output result (first line code) the three object returned. Each object have this structure: appointments, unavailables

Comment: Kind of looks like your for loop assumes that response.length is going to equal the value in id_users_provider - are you sure that is true?  e.g. there are no missing items in response[]?

Comment: @Dillinger -  I was hoping to see what appointments, unavailables look like in each object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mistake in your condition in array key, change `z` to `0`:

```
for(var z = 0; z < response.length; z++)
{
    if(response[z]['unavailables'][0] != undefined) // <== here
    {
         var id_operatore = response[z]['unavailables'][0].id_users_provider;
         console.log(id_operatore);
    }
}
```